# Правильное хранение истории изменений мест работы в БД

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Вопрос о том, как хранить историю изменений обьекта, кроме записи всех действий в лог. Например, есть класс работодатели:

```
public class Companies
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Worker> Workers { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

И есть класс работника:

```
public class Worker
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public int CurrentCompanyId { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Допустим, работник увольняется из одной компании и устраивается в другую. Какой самый оптимальный способ хранить историю изменений мест работы работника?

Comment: добавьте таблицу Юзер-Компания и пишите туда эту инфу

Comment: "Самый правильный способ" -- вещь жутко условная в такой ситуации. Допустим, как вам такой вариант: есть таблица company, есть таблица people и  есть таблица employee (PeopleID, CompanyID, DateFrom, DateTo). Я вам уточнил заголовок, потому что если расширять вопрос до просто "хранение истории", то мы так придём к системе а-ля 1С Бухгалтерия, где можно посмотреть значение на любую дату. А, ещё. Начните с вопроса "зачем это всё хранить?", чтобы понимать, какую задачу вы решаете -- тогда вам будет проще выбрать более правильную структуру.